# spring bean initialization depends on variable number of other beans

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

In my Spring/Grails/Groovy app, I configure some cache beans:

```
rulesCache(InMemoryCache){..}
countriesCache(InMemoryCache){..}

myService(ServiceBean){
  cache = ref('rulesCache')
}
```

A cache manager provides specialized services when retrieving caches, so I give the manager a list of cache beans:

```
cacheMgr(CacheManager){
  caches = [ ref('rulesCache'), ref('countriesCache')]
}
```

Services must get cache beans from the manager, they can't be "wired in" (the manager returns a cache delegate, not the cache itself, that's why), so I got around this problem by doing:

```
  cacheMgr(CacheManager){
    caches = [ ref('rulesCache'), ref('countriesCache')]
  }

  cacheMgrDelegate(MethodInvokingFactoryBean) { bean ->
      bean.dependsOn = ['cacheMgr']
      targetObject = cacheMgr
      targetMethod = 'getManager'
   }

   myService(SomeService){
     cache = "#{cacheMgrDelegate.getCache('rulesCache')}"
   }
```

This works fine, but cache beans are arbitrary, so I can't provide a list to the manager. I managed to get around this problem by listening for post initialization events from cache type objects, and registering each cache manually with the manager:

```
CacheManager implements BeanPostProcessor {
    postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName){
      if(bean instanceof ICache)
         registerCache(bean)
      return bean
    }
}
```

## Problem

The issue is that Spring is doing initialization on `myService` before `cacheManager` registers all cache beans, so `getCache()` returns null:

```
myService(SomeService){
   cache = "#{cacheMgrDelegate.getCache('rulesCache')}"
}
```

I understand why it's happening. I can't use `dependsOn` since cache beans are arbitrary, and this is where I'm stuck.

## Possible Solution

During spring config phase, `CacheManager.getCache(name)` could return a lightweight "proxy"-like object while saving a reference to each proxy generated:

```
getCache(String name){
  CacheProxy proxy = createProxy()
  proxies.add(proxy)
  return proxy
}
```

After all beans are configured and app context is set, `cacheManager` simply iterates the list of proxies and completes initialization:

```
onApplicationContext(){
   proxies.each{ proxy ->
     completeInit(proxy)
   }
}
```

Is there a better option? I'm out of ideas :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply autowire all instances of `ICache` instead? It should create necessary dependencies between `CacheManager` and the caches:

```
CacheManager {
    @Autowired
    public void setCaches(List<ICache> caches) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh, did not know spring could generate `List` from generic types and autowire at the same time, this is perfect as it solves the problem of arbitrary cache beans; very elegant! thank you!